# How to store tcolorbox's (multiple) settings in a macro?

Tags: macros, expansion, pgfkeys, tcolorbox

I'd like to store `tcolorbox`' (multiple) settings in a (single) macro (in fact, a `xkeyval`'s `\cmdKV@fam@key` macro) and use them afterwards via this macro (I know I should use `pgfkeys` instead, but my whole class is using `xkeyval`). Probably because of a `pgfkeys` expansion trouble, I can't succeed: for instance, `colback=red` is a regular option of the `tcolorbox`'s `tcolorbox` environment, but it can't be stored in a macro, as pointed out by the following MWE (which involves only a single setting for simplicity):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%
\newcommand*\foo{colback=red}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[\foo]
Test.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

which leads to the following error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/colback=red'
```

How could I circumvent this problem?

Comment: I can understand you're used to `xkeyval`; however, `\tcbset{foo/.style={colback=red}}` and `\begin{tcolorbox}[foo]` does the trick. You'd have the same problem with `xkeyval`, as it doesn't expand the tokens passed in `\setkeys`.

Comment: Is this related with "[Is it possible to reuse tcolorbox definitions in another tcolorbox definition?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180898/1952)" ?

Comment: @egreg I already knew how to "manually" define styles and how to use them. My question was about defining them in "one go" from a macro.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the combination of the `code` option plus `\pgfkeysalsofrom` from `pgfkeys` you can use options stored in a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%
\newcommand*\foo{colback=red,colframe=red!50!black}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[code={\pgfkeysalsofrom\foo}]
Test.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a similar mechanism in `\begin{tikzpicture}[\pgfkeysalsofrom...]...\end{tikzpicture}`?

Comment: @lyl Not by default, but you can set `\tikzset{code/.code={#1}}`. Then, you can do `\begin{tikzpicture}[code={\pgfkeysalsofrom\foo}]`.