# tcolorbox package: How to reuse/extend tcbhighmath default settings

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, tikz-styles

I'm using the `tcolorbox` package and want to *customize* the settings for `\tcbhighmath` settings. However, using `\tcbset{highlight math style={...}}` *resets* all the settings that I don't touch.

I want something like `\tcbset{highlight math style+={...}}`

I failed to find *either*

- a way to do that, *or*
- as a hack, documentation on the defaults for `highlight math style` (it's claimed to have no defaults, but the `\tcbhighmath` clearly differs from `\tcboxmath`), *or*
- as a hack, documentation on how to print those defaults.

The only working hack I have is to *wrap* `\tcbhighmath` to pass my custom settings. That prevents using other `tcbhighmath` options.

I'm sure those docs exist somewhere within the tikz/tcolorbox manuals, but they total ~1800 pages and I'm no tikz expert, so I'm declaring defeat after maybe 1 hour. Even

```
\pgfkeys{/tcb/highlight math style/.show code}
```

only shows the following, which doesn't show the default color:

```
> \pgfkeysshower=\long macro:
#1\pgfeov ->\pgfkeysalso {highlight math/.style={notitle,nophantom,#1}}.
\pgfkeys@code ...keysshower }\show \pgfkeysshower
```

See below my MWE. The problem doesn't disappear when moving `\renewcommand` / `\tcbset` outside the frame; that's just for illustration.

```latex
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\hl[1]{\tcbhighmath{#1}}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Test}
  \begin{align*}
    \hl{1}+1={}&2 
  \end{align*}

  % I want to tweak the settings for tcbhighmath.
  % Works:
  \renewcommand\hl[1]{\tcbhighmath[left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm]{#1}}

  \begin{align*}
    \hl{1}+1={}&2 
  \end{align*}

  % Doesn't work — it also resets the color for tcbhighmath:
  \renewcommand\hl[1]{\tcbhighmath{#1}}
  \tcbset{highlight math style={left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm}}

  \begin{align*}
    \hl{1}+1={}&2 
  \end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered output]

Comment: After writing the question, the website suggests
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180898/1340 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183078/1340; they might be related, but I'm not sure how to apply those ideas — I don't want to inherit from a given style, but to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

From the source code, `highlight math style` is defined by

```
\tcbset{
  highlight math style/.style={highlight math/.style={notitle,nophantom,#1}}
}
```

and initialized by

```
\tcbset{
  highlight math style={colframe=red,colback=yellow!25!white}
}
```

This is equivalent to

```
\tcbset{
  highlight math/.style={notitle,nophantom,colframe=red,colback=yellow!25!white}
}
```

When you use `\tcbset{highlight math style={left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm}}`, style `highlight math` is redefined and the initial `colframe=red,colback=yellow!25!white` part is lost, so the result differs.

You can copy-and-paste the `colframe=red,colback=yellow!25!white` to `highlight math style={...}`.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\hl[1]{\tcbhighmath{#1}}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Test}
  \begin{align*}
    \hl{1}+1={}&2 
  \end{align*}

  % I want to tweak the settings for tcbhighmath.
  % Works:
  \renewcommand\hl[1]{\tcbhighmath[left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm]{#1}}

  \begin{align*}
    \hl{1}+1={}&2 
  \end{align*}

  % Works as well:
  \renewcommand\hl[1]{\tcbhighmath{#1}}
  \tcbset{highlight math style={
    colframe=red, colback=yellow!25!white,
    left=0mm, right=0mm, top=0mm, bottom=0mm
  }}

  \begin{align*}
    \hl{1}+1={}&2 
  \end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Update:

You may also define a new opton

```
\tcbset{
  highlight math style app/.style={highlight math/.append style={#1}}
}
```

and then use

```
\tcbset{highlight math style app={
  left=0mm, right=0mm, top=0mm, bottom=0mm
}}
```