# PGF keys passing arguments to multiple environments

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, optional-arguments, pgfkeys, textpos

I'd like to combine both [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and [textpos](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) to place boxes to a specific position in a page.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\makeatletter

%% #1: options
%% #2: textblock width
%% #3: textblock position
\newenvironment{tcolorboxat}[3][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/tcbat/.is family,
    /tcbat/.cd,
    ho/.initial = 0,
    vo/.initial = 0,
    #1,
  }%
  \begin{textblock*}{#2}[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcbat/ho},\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcbat/vo}](#3)%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[]%
}{\end{tcolorbox}\end{textblock*}}%

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorboxat}[ho=0.5]{5cm}{3cm,8cm}
  This is a tcolorbox placed at 3cm, 8cm from top left corner of the page. Origin point is 1.5cm, 8cm.
\end{tcolorboxat}
\end{document}
```

This works as expected. Now I would like to add a `tcb opts` style like option to pass to the `tcolorbox` environment:

```
\newenvironment{tcolorboxat}[3][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/tcbat/.is family,
    /tcbat/.cd,
    ho/.initial = 0,
    vo/.initial = 0,
    tcb opts/.style = { title = box title },
    #1,
  }%
  \begin{textblock*}{#2}[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcbat/ho},\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcbat/vo}](#3)%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[code=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcbat/tcb opts}]%
}{\end{tcolorbox}\end{textblock*}}%
```

unfortunately this does not works, the `title` option does not seem to be passed to `tcolorbox`.

Is there a way to put all `tcolorbox` options into a style like key similar to something like that?

```
\begin{tcolorboxat}[ho=0.4,
    tcb opts = {
      title = box title,
      colback = red,
  }]{5cm}{3cm,8cm}
  ...
\end{tcolorboxat}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a typo : `tcp opts` is not `tcb opts`... Then, replace `code=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcbat/tcp opts}` by `/tcbat/tcb opts`.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180898/1952

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \tcbuselibrary{breakable}
  \tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\makeatletter

\pgfkeys{/tcbat/.is family,
  /tcbat/.cd,
  ho/.store in = \mytcbat@ho,
  vo/.store in = \mytcbat@vo,
  tcb opts/.code = {\tcbset{mytcboptions/.style={#1}}},
}%
%

%% #1: options
%% #2: textblock width
%% #3: textblock position
\newenvironment{tcolorboxat}[3][]{%
  \tcbset{mytcboptions/.style={}}%  %% Reinitialize new style
  %
  \pgfkeys{/tcbat, ho=0, vo=0, #1}%  %% Set defaults, whatever you may want them to be...
  %
  \begin{textblock*}{#2}[\mytcbat@ho, \mytcbat@vo](#3)%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[mytcboptions]%
}{\end{tcolorbox}\end{textblock*}}%

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorboxat}[ho=0.5, tcb opts={unbreakable, enhanced, title={Testing 123}}]{5cm}{3cm,8cm}
  This is a tcolorbox placed at 3cm, 8cm from top left corner of the page. Origin point is 1.5cm, 8cm.
\end{tcolorboxat}

\tcbset{%
  %% Define a new skin for tcolorbox called title3d
  title3d/.style = {%
      skin=enhancedlast jigsaw,
      tikznode boxed title={inner sep=1mm, align=left},
      attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-4mm,yshift=-0.5mm},
      fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
      colbacktitle=blue!45!white,
      colframe=red!50!black,
      interior style={top color=blue!10!white,bottom color=red!10!white},
      boxed title style={empty,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt},
      underlay boxed title={
          \fill[blue!45!white] (title.north west) -- (title.north east)
              -- +(\tcboxedtitleheight-1mm,-\tcboxedtitleheight+1mm)
              -- ([xshift=4mm,yshift=0.5mm]frame.north east) -- +(0mm,-1mm)
              -- (title.south west) -- cycle;
          \fill[blue!45!white!50!black] ([yshift=-0.5mm]frame.north west)
              -- +(-0.4,0) -- +(0,-0.3) -- cycle;
          \fill[blue!45!white!50!black] ([yshift=-0.5mm]frame.north east)
              -- +(0,-0.3) -- +(0.4,0) -- cycle; },
  },
}

\begin{tcolorboxat}[ho=0.5, tcb opts={unbreakable, enhanced, title3d, title={So pretty}}]{7cm}{6cm,14cm}
  This is a tcolorbox placed at 6cm, 14cm from top left corner of the page.
\end{tcolorboxat}
\end{document}
```

**Output**:

[image: Output associated to code above]

Answer (score 0):

@feculededentier this solution does the job. Thanks.

Meanwhile I am still wondering what is the best practice to declare `PFG` keys style options since this code also works:

```
\newenvironment{tcolorboxat}[3][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/tcb/tcbat/.style = {},
    /tcbat/.is family,
    /tcbat/.cd,
    ho/.initial = 0,
    vo/.initial = 0,
    tcb opts/.code = {\tcbset{tcbat/.style={##1}}},
    #1,
    ho/.get = \tcbat@ho,
    vo/.get = \tcbat@vo,
  }
  \begin{textblock*}{#2} [\tcbat@ho, \tcbat@vo](#3)
    \begin{tcolorbox}[tcbat]%
}{\end{tcolorbox}\end{textblock*}}%
```

The advantage is that all declarations are in one scope. But many people seem to declare the `PGF` keys outside of the environment declaration.

Comment: Good question: I can't give a complete answer to it. I don't know if the scoping could cause an issue if you tried to embed a `tcolorboxat` within another `tcolorboxat` (this doesn't make any sense in your context anyway). The main reason why I declare my `PGF` keys outside of my environments is because I often use the same `pgfkeys` for many different environments and also because I provide macros to globally reset a default value.

Comment: For example, I might declare `\newcommand{\tcbat@ho@default}{0}` outside the `pgfkeys` (and environment) and also create `\newcommand{\setdefaultho}[1]{\renewcommand{\tcbat@ho@default}{#1}}`. This value could then be used inside the `tcolorboxat` definition I have provided by using `\pgfkeys{/tcbat, ho=\tcbat@ho@default, vo=0, #1}`. The `ho/.initial = 0` key therefore becomes useless (not needed), but you have to add a `ho/.code` to compensate...

Comment: Ok. Since this is for a pet project I guess having it locally defined good enough. Thanks again.