# How to create theorem boxes

Tags: environments, boxes, tcolorbox

I wrote a chapter for a book, and we use a structure.tex with a lot of definitios and macros. Now I'm writing other book and I would like to use those kind of boxes as below.

[image: Example]

Note that when the box can't be in a single page, it divides in two and the box is not closed in the first page. 
Basically are two tipes of boxes.

I have the `structure.tex`. I tried to write a new `.tex` but there are a lot of errors and I have been all day trying make it work. There are various packages I can't understant. [structure.tex](https://app.box.com/s/i47uhxg61a4cfuw2cwlvebzfoszc3ymg)

How can I define those things as \begin{name}.. \end{name} ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be quite easily achieved with [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}{
  enhanced,
  sharp corners,
  attach boxed title to top left={
    yshifttext=-1mm
  },
  colback=white,
  colframe=blue!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  boxed title style={
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    colback=blue!75!black,
    colframe=blue!75!black,
  } 
}{thm}
\newtcbtheorem[no counter]{Proof}{Proof}{
  enhanced,
  sharp corners,
  attach boxed title to top left={
    yshifttext=-1mm
  },
  colback=white,
  colframe=blue!25,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    colback=blue!25,
    colframe=blue!25,
  } 
}{prf}

\begin{document}
\begin{Theorem}{}{fermat}
  No three positive integers \(a\), \(b\) and \(c\) satisfy the equation \(a^{n}
  + b^{n} = c^{n}\) for any integer greater than two.
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Proof}{Theorem \ref{thm:fermat}}{}
  The proof is easy, but too large to fit in this box.
\end{Proof}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Have a read in its documentation for what each setting does (I will admit, the defaults are a little annoying, hence why there are so many options).  It also supports breaking boxes across pages!

Comment: You can use `\tcbset` to define `.styles` to be reused as needed. See: [Is it possible to reuse tcolorbox definitions in another tcolorbox definition?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180898/1952)