# Adding an "mdtheorem" (i.e. with frametitle) to a List of Theorems

Tags: theorems, mdframed, thmtools

I'm having trouble with either formatting `newmdtheoremenv` environments, or adding `mdtheorem` environments to a table of theorems, depending on how you look at it.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{guidelinestyle}{% 
  linecolor=black,
  linewidth=1pt,
  frametitlerule=true,
  frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!20,
  innertopmargin=\topskip,
} 
% \newmdenv[style=guidelinestyle]{asEnv}{asEnv}[section]
\newmdtheoremenv[style=guidelinestyle]{asTheoremEnv}{asTheoremEnv}[section]
\mdtheorem[style=guidelinestyle]{asTheorem}{asTheorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\expandafter\csname ver@mdframed.sty\endcsname

%\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show=xxx]  % this is how I actually display it in my document
\listoftheorems

\section{My section}

% \begin{asEnv}[As environment, it appears in ToTh]
%   But it doesn't look like what I want.
% \end{asEnv}

\begin{asTheoremEnv}[As theoremEnv, it appears in ToTh]
  But it doesn't look like what I want.
\end{asTheoremEnv}

\begin{asTheorem}[As theorem, it does not appear in ToTh]
 But it looks a lot better!
\end{asTheorem}

\end{document}
```

This produces a document that looks like:

[image: MWE PDF]

I have found [this issue](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed/issues/1) which describes the same problem, but as it dates back to April 2012 and my version of `mdframed` is from 2013, I think it should not be applicable (and I cannot see in what version it should have been solved).

What I'd want instead, is the environment to look like the latter in the document, but appear in the table of theorems.

Is there somebody who can help me with getting this to work? 
I don't really care about what exact packages are being used, if

- it appears in the list of theorems, and
- the theorems have a border and some kind of highlighted title bar

Comment: Do you require the use of `mdframed` or would you consider using [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)?  You can see it being used for theorems in [one of my answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296467/26980) and cmhughes provides a [nice implementation of List of Theorems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87437/26980) as well as other "List of ...".

Comment: @JP-Ellis I am not married to `mdframed` in any way. `tcolorbox` looks like a great alternative, the only thing I will have to make work with that, is ensuring that it doesn't conflict with my use of TikZ and its `external` library. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can teach `thmtools` to use `\mdtheorem` as its `\newtheorem` command.  A hint is in the `thmtools` documentation about how it treats the `thmbox` option.

If you introduce a new `mdthm` key as:

```
\makeatletter
\define@key{thmdef}{mdthm}[{}]{%
\thmt@trytwice{\def\thmt@theoremdefiner{\mdtheorem[#1]}}{}}
\makeatother
```

then you can write

```
\declaretheorem[mdthm={style=guidelinestyle},numberwithin=section]{theorem}
```

passing the `mdframed` options as the argument to `mdthm`.  This produces the theorem style you request and entries in the list of theorems:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{guidelinestyle}{% 
  linecolor=black,
  linewidth=1pt,
  frametitlerule=true,
  frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!20,
  innertopmargin=\topskip,
} 

\makeatletter
\define@key{thmdef}{mdthm}[{}]{%
\thmt@trytwice{\def\thmt@theoremdefiner{\mdtheorem[#1]}}{}}
\makeatother
\declaretheorem[mdthm={style=guidelinestyle},numberwithin=section]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\listoftheorems

\section{My section}

\begin{theorem}[Is in list of theorems!]
  Text.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```