# Avoiding Page Break - Box for Theorems

Tags: page-breaking, boxes, tcolorbox

I was using `tcolorbox` for creating a new box for theorems following this post: [How to create theorem boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296463/how-to-create-theorem-boxes).

The problem is that it's not avoiding page breaks. I used a box on a pretty big proof, and it is starting on a new page. Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem with the `tcolorbox`? Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}`, and add the option `breakable` in the options of the box you create. This way, it will separate the box between two boxes if a pagebreak is needed.

Comment: The OP is looking for the oposite situation: How to avoid the page break, but not how to permit it.

Comment: @Cragfelt -- please reread the question.  the complaint is that the box with the large proof is starting on the next page, and the op wants to avoid that.  i think the op's native language most likely isn't english.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I appreciate you pointed it out. Now I can see it.