# How to build shortcut from parametrized environment

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

I have defined a parametrized tcolorbox environment like this based on some existing post from this community.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{maincolor}{HTML}{1A1279} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mycb}[1][calculator]{
  breakable,enhanced,arc=0mm,colback=maincolor!5,colframe=maincolor!80,leftrule=12mm,%
  overlay={
    \node[anchor=north west,outer sep=2pt] at (frame.north west) {\includegraphics[width=8mm]{#1}}; 
  }
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{mycb}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{mycb}

\begin{mycb}[question]
  \lipsum[1]
\end{mycb}

% \begin{mycbquestion}
%   \lipsum[1]
% \end{mycb}

\end{document}
```

So by default it would use my calculator image. I can pass the name of the picture to use. It works fine.

I would like to have some "shortcuts" so that I do not have to type the name of few pictures for recurring cases. Like question and equation that could be used as environment mycbquestion and mycbequation.

How should I proceed without copy pasting the definition up to the name of the picture? I am confused how to do that with an environment.

Regards,

jm

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please provide a complete, small working example (beginning with `\documentclass`), rather than just a code snippet.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, thank you for the warm welcome.
I edited the post with the full test document.
I would like to have the definition of the environment that is commented from the definition of the existing mycb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another solution where as many as needed styles are defined as new tcolorboxes. To save some typing, a paramètric general style is defined and used inside the newtcolorbox definitions. If you need a particular style which has not been defined, you can always use the default parameter to adjust the design (see third box based on second one)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{
    myboxstyle/.style={
        breakable,
        enhanced,
        sharp corners,
        colback=red!5,
        colframe=red!80,
        leftrule=12mm,
        overlay={\node[anchor=north west,outer sep=2pt] at (frame.north west) {\includegraphics[width=8mm]{#1}}; }
    }
}

\newtcolorbox{mycalc}[1][]{
  myboxstyle=example-image,
  #1
}

\newtcolorbox{myAbox}[1][]{
  myboxstyle=example-image-A,
  #1
}

\newtcolorbox{myBbox}[1][]{
  myboxstyle=example-image-B,
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mycalc}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mycalc}

\begin{myAbox}[myboxstyle=example-image-C, colframe=green]
\lipsum[3]
\end{myAbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a nice approach. Could you please explain from where the syntax of myboxstyle\.style is coming? I am looking at the colorbox manual and find no reference to it. It would help me understand how to be more efficient using the documentation.

Comment: @jmt As an answer, take a look at [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180898/1952) and corresponding Gonzalo's answer and comments.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. It does explain that part of the syntax. It is present in the tcolorbox manual but not with such details useful for novice like me.

Comment: @jmt Everything about `pgfkeys` is explained in section 87 `Keys Management` in [`pgf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) (`TikZ`) documentation. But I recommend to start with the amazing tutorials at the beginning of this document.

Answer (score 1):

Does this suffice?  Here, a second environment `repeatcb` uses the most recent image from `mycb`.  Alternatively, there is a `mycbB` environment, that calls on `mycb` with a particular (oft-used) image.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{maincolor}{HTML}{1A1279} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\def\mycbtext{}

\newtcolorbox{mycb}[1][example-image]{%
  breakable,enhanced,arc=0mm,colback=maincolor!5,colframe=maincolor!80,leftrule=12mm,%
  overlay={
    \node[anchor=north west,outer sep=2pt] at (frame.north west) {%
  \includegraphics[width=8mm]{#1}};}\gdef\recentcbimage{#1}%
}
\newenvironment{repeatcb}{\begin{mycb}[\recentcbimage]}{\end{mycb}}
\newenvironment{mycbB}{\begin{mycb}[example-image-b]}{\end{mycb}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{mycb}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{mycb}

\begin{mycb}[example-image-a]
  \lipsum[1]
\end{mycb}

\begin{repeatcb}
   \lipsum[1]
\end{repeatcb}

\begin{mycbB}
   \lipsum[1]
\end{mycbB}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I know how to define new environment reusing the first one as a template.
```
\newenvironment{mycbB}{\begin{mycb}[example-image-b]}{\end{mycb}}
```
That was what I was failing to understand with LaTeX. Somehow I was looking for something like a command.
The idea to save the last used image in a variable and then use it later is nice. I never thought about something like with my current LaTeX knowledge.