# Inside of a \newtcbinputlisting how can I change the color of the line number as well as specify line numbers from an existing script?

Tags: tcolorbox, minted

I am working on code-highlighting using pygments through the minted package.

I am wondering how I can change the color of the line number text on the left side of the highlighted code block to use with different styles.  When I use a darker style, the column text color is still black and I want to change it depending on the style.  I can change the col background and tcb background color just fine.

Here is the output:
[image]

Here is my preamble that references the code highlighting:

```
%%% ====================================================================
%%% Custom code highlighting using Minted and tikz
%%% ====================================================================

\usepackage{tikz}

%%% ====================================================================
%%% Specific colors used for code highlighting
%%% ====================================================================

\definecolor{pythoncodebg}{rgb}{0.99,1,0.99} % light green

% TCB colorbox to put higlighted minted code from pygments inside
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle[python]{default} % Specific color scheme if I invoke \inputminted{python}{path_to_code.py}

%%% ====================================================================
%%% Custom code highlighting using Minted
%%% ====================================================================

% Python normalsize
\newtcbinputlisting{\pythoninput}[2][]{%
    listing file={#2},
    minted language=python,
    minted style=default,
    minted options={
        fontsize=\normal,
        linenos,
        numbersep=1mm,
        breaklines=true,
    },% <-- put other minted options inside the brackets
    overlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \fill[gray!25] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}
    },
    colback=pythoncodebg,
    colframe=black!70,
    before skip=5pt plus 2pt,
    breakable,
    enhanced,% <-- put other tcolorbox options here
    listing only,#1
}
```

In my main .tex file, here is how I call the command:

```
\pythoninput{code/python/Code1.py}
```

The second question I have is how do I specify line numbers using a custom \newtcbinputlisting command?
I would like to replace the following tex script:

```
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=bgp]   
    \inputminted[fontsize=\tiny,firstline=12,lastline=35]{python}{./Code/Python/QuadStiffnessShort_Axi.py}
\end{mdframed}
```

with something similar to:

```
\pythoninput[firstline=12,lastline=35]{code/python/Code1.py}
```

So that I don't have to use mdframed and can simply use the tcbcolorbox with all of the options I have specified.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [`minted` package](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) documentation in CTAN (or your computer), you will see that `linenos` option enables line numbers and that the aspect of these line numbers is hard-coded in command `\thefancyVerbLine`. You can change it introducing and adapting following code in your preamble

```
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\sffamily
    \textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,1.0}{\scriptsize
        \oldstylenums{\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}}
```

When the `minted options` are fixed in your listings style, you can add options with `minted options app` hook.

```
\documentclass{article}
%%% ====================================================================
%%% Custom code highlighting using Minted and tikz
%%% ====================================================================

\usepackage{tikz}

%%% ====================================================================
%%% Specific colors used for code highlighting
%%% ====================================================================

\definecolor{pythoncodebg}{rgb}{0.99,1,0.99} % light green

% TCB colorbox to put higlighted minted code from pygments inside
\usepackage[most, minted]{tcolorbox}
%\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable,hooks}

%\usepackage{minted} %already charged with tcblibrary minted
\usemintedstyle[python]{default} % Specific color scheme if I invoke \inputminted{python}{path_to_code.py}

%%% ====================================================================
%%% Custom code highlighting using Minted
%%% ====================================================================

% Python normalsize
\newtcbinputlisting{\pythoninput}[2][]{%
    listing file={#2},
    minted language=python,
    minted style=default,
    minted options={
        fontsize=\normalsize,
        linenos,
        numbersep=1mm,
        breaklines=true,
    },% <-- put other minted options inside the brackets
    overlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \fill[gray!25] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}
    },
    colback=pythoncodebg,
    colframe=black!70,
    before skip=5pt plus 2pt,
    breakable,
    enhanced,% <-- put other tcolorbox options here
    listing only,#1,
    }

\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\ttfamily
    \textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{\small{\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}}

\begin{document}

\pythoninput{PythonCode1.py}

\pythoninput[minted options app={firstline=2,lastline=3}, colback=purple!10]{PythonCode1.py}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  As a follow-up question, is it possible to add that portion of code inside of the `\newtcbinputlisting` so that you can have multiple unique languages being highlighted?  For example \pythonDARK and \pythonLIGHT and be able to switch between them if need be.

Comment: @ChristopherCreveling I'm not sure to understand what "portion of code" you want to keep or change. You can declare `tcolorbox` styles like in `TiKZ` (look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180898/1952). This way you can input the desired style as the optional parameter in `\pythoninput` to change listing design,